# Why my PC got frame drops even on Desktop in idle?

Tags: windows-10, performance, freeze

In the last month my Windows PC get frame drops after about an hour(e.g. when moving the explorer). After two or three hours windows lags even in explorrer and browser if every thing is closed. After four hours windows is unusable. After a restart everything is fine (so no temperature problems).

Following hardware is used:

- i7 8700K
- ASUS GeForce GTX 1070 Ti STRIX Advanced
- MSI Z370-A PRO (MS-7B48)
- G.Skill DIMM 16 GB DDR4-3200 Kit
- be quiet STRAIGHT POWER 10 600W, PC- Netzteil
- Windows 10 - Version 1903 (18362.356)
- 1x 1TB Crucial MX500 SSD
- 1x WD10EZEX 1TB

I have already done a reset via windows (with keeping data). The windows 10 memory test was negative (no errors). Temperature of CPU, GPU, mainboard is ok (50 °C on gaming).

What may cause these problems?

If this isn't the right comunity for this question I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 v1903 is know to slow down PC's so I suggest you download and install Windows 10 v1809 and don't update it for now...v1909 is coming soon, its better to update after that because 1909 is going to focus mainly on improving the current v1903.(download drivers yourself). Open the following link: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Then on the page there is no option to download v1809 so in chrome right click on the page and click "Inspect", In the inspect window click on the three dotted menu in the top right corner

click "More tools"

Click "Network Conditions"

Under "User Agent" uncheck "Select Automatically"

From the dropdown select "Android 4.0.2 Browser" and refresh the page.

Scroll down and under "Select Edition" Choose "Windows 10 October 2018 Update"